# add image to asp:linkbutton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

how to add a background image to my asp:linkbutton using code behind? I want to change the background image once the link is clicked? thx

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="home" runat="server">home</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: It would be better to simply change its `CssClass` and let the image and other design-related things at your CSS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in page_load event when you click and make a postback change image

 if (IsPostBack)
       {                  
                 ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/newimage.gif";                           

       }
```

Comment: this is an image button, i want to change the image background with link button, because I just want to change the background image and have the text stay the same, so if i need to change the text e.g. home I can do it, i hope it makes sense what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Ben What if on imagebutton mouse click event you redirect the page to the desired links?